# Confluence Java Error on Notifications Tab

Tags: java, linux, debian, jira, confluence

I am using Confluence version 7.4.0 running on a Debian 8 machine with Postgresql server 9.6

On any page there is a notification icon in the top right corner where I can normally see all the last actions that have been made.

If I click on this icon, I am currently getting a very long java error but can not identify what is the root cause and how to solve it:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.AbstractI18NResource.getBundle(AbstractI18NResource.java:23)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.I18NResourceBundlesLoader.getResourceBundles(I18NResourceBundlesLoader.java:42)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.DefaultI18NBeanFactory.loadResourceBundles(DefaultI18NBeanFactory.java:239)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.DefaultI18NBeanFactory.getStandardResourceBundles(DefaultI18NBeanFactory.java:170)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.DefaultI18NBeanFactory.buildBundles(DefaultI18NBeanFactory.java:95)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.DefaultI18NBeanFactory.getI18NBean(DefaultI18NBeanFactory.java:278)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.CachingI18NBeanFactory.lambda$getI18NBean$0(CachingI18NBeanFactory.java:78)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.lambda$null$1(UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.lambda$get$2(UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.get(UnblockingRemovalJvmCache.java:50)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.i18n.CachingI18NBeanFactory.getI18NBean(CachingI18NBeanFactory.java:75)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor642.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.util.ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.java:26)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy538.getI18NBean(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor642.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.bridge.external.HostComponentFactoryBean$DynamicServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(HostComponentFactoryBean.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy538.getI18NBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.sal.confluence.message.ConfluenceI18nResolver.getAllTranslationsForPrefix(ConfluenceI18nResolver.java:74)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor758.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1900.getAllTranslationsForPrefix(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.service.ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.addI18n(ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.java:174)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.service.ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.createRegistration(ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.java:158)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.service.ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.createRegistrations(ClientRegistrationServiceImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2887.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy858.createRegistrations(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.getLastModifiedInternal(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:204)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.access$200(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl$6.call(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:195)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl$6.call(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:192)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.util.concurrent.LockedTaskExecutor.tryExecuteUnderLock(LockedTaskExecutor.java:47)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.util.concurrent.LockedTaskExecutor.executeUnderLock(LockedTaskExecutor.java:96)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.getLastModified(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:192)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.service.LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.getCacheValue(LocalRegistrationServiceImpl.java:223)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.servlet.ServletRenderer.renderWithAnchor(ServletRenderer.java:71)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.servlet.ServletRenderer.renderWithAnchor(ServletRenderer.java:43)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.host.servlet.NotificationsMiniviewServlet.doGet(NotificationsMiniviewServlet.java:19)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DelegatingPluginServlet.service(DelegatingPluginServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.ServletModuleContainerServlet.service(ServletModuleContainerServlet.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.servlet.ServletModuleContainerServlet.service(ServletModuleContainerServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.baseurl.IncludeResourcesFilter.doFilter(IncludeResourcesFilter.java:52)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.refinedwiki.confluence.plugins.theme.original.filters.StartSiteFilter.doFilter(StartSiteFilter.java:58)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.pulp.PulpFilter.doFilter(PulpFilter.java:70)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.UniversalAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(UniversalAnalyticsFilter.java:92)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.efi.OnboardingFilter.doFilter(OnboardingFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.mobile.filter.MobileAppWebViewFilter.doFilter(MobileAppWebViewFilter.java:58)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.plugin.servlet.filter.JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.message.MessagesDecoratorFilter.doFilter(MessagesDecoratorFilter.java:65)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.profiling.ProfilingSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ProfilingSiteMeshFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.profiling.ConfluenceActivityFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceActivityFilter.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.plugin.servlet.filter.JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.ServletContextThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ServletContextThreadLocalFilter.java:17)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.UserLoggingContextFilter.doFilter(UserLoggingContextFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.UserNameHeaderFilter.doFilter(UserNameHeaderFilter.java:25)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.MauEventFilter.doFilterInternal(MauEventFilter.java:31)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.AbstractStaticResourceAwareFilter.doFilter(AbstractStaticResourceAwareFilter.java:43)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceTimeoutFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceTimeoutFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.HttpSessionRegistrarFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionRegistrarFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceSecurityFilter.applyFilter(ConfluenceSecurityFilter.java:40)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceSecurityFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceSecurityFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:94)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.doFilter(AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.plugin.servlet.filter.JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(JohnsonServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.util.ClusterHeaderFilter.doFilter(ClusterHeaderFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:170)
```

Due to the limitation of length in a question, I cannot reproduce the full error, so here it is: https://paste.ee/p/9bNJX

Comment: Is your profile language set to English? If not, try changing it to that and see what happens. It looks like there's a problem somewhere loading a translation.

Comment: I changed the profile language to english, but nothing changed. the error message still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The error was caused by a plugin failure i used.